# Is quantum mechanics "the most successful scientific theory in the history of the human race?"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history

I was reading a layman's article about quantum entanglement and came across this line about quantum theory in general:

> "But the math, the predictions starting in the 1920s, have all turned out to be correct," he said. "It's the most successful scientific theory in the human race."

At first that struck me as grandiose but the more I thought about it the more it made sense. I mean, the electronic and digital revolutions themselves are products of it. What do experts think about this statement?

Here's the article btw: [Link](https://www.insider.com/quantum-entanglement-einstein-first-picture-2019-7)

Comment: I see that you got a couple of good answers before your question was put on hold, but if you substituted the word "accurate" for "successful" the reasons for the hold would disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm quoting an article, so the hold should probably stay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just say that it is hard for any physicist to argue against that statement.

In physics, we don't rank the theories or laws to decide which one is the best. Each of them exists because they work under certain conditions and each of them have their own limits.

However, we are yet to do any experiment where quantum mechanics breaks down. So far the closest competitor we have had is the theory of general relativity but we realized that even that breaks down under certain conditions (center of black hole). This is not to say that we have equations in quantum mechanics that explains what happens at the center of black hole, but we know for sure that the equations for general relativity doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Feynman gave the following example of the success of quantum electrodynamics in accounting for the functioning of the physical world we inhabit: It is as if QED allowed you to *predict*, based on first principles, the distance between Los Angeles and New York City- and then, when the actual measurement was made, to have your prediction match reality to within the thickness of a single sheet of paper.

Successes like this give scientists good reason to accept the fundamental validity of the quantum picture, even though it's also well-understood that there are (extreme) circumstances in which the quantum picture is known to be incomplete, as pointed out by LostCause above.